# Expected value, variance and hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, variance

> Marco plays the following simplified lotto game: from an urn
> containing 10 balls numbered from 1 to 10, 4 balls are extracted without
> reinsertion. Marco bets on the pair of numbers {5, 10}. Let X be the
> random variable that counts how many numbers Marco guesses, i.e. how
> many of the numbers {5, 10} are extracted.
>
> a) Identify the type of distribution of X, and calculate its expected
> value and variance.

My attempt:

I think that I can use a hypergeometric random variable (because, among other things, it says that the extraction process is without reinsertion).

$P(X=k) = \frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{{\binom{n}{r}}}$ where n is the total number of elements that we have (in this case, n==10), m is equal to 2 (5 and 10) and r is equal to the number of extracted elements (in this case, r==4).

$P(X=0) = \frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{10-2}{4-0}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{8}{4}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{1}{3}$

$P(X=1) = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{10-2}{4-1}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{3}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{8}{15}$

$P(X=2) = \frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{10-2}{4-2}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{2}{15}$

- $E(X) = 0p(0) + 1p(1) + 2p(2) = 0P(X=0) + 1P(X=1) + 2P(X=2) = 0\frac{1}{3} + 1\frac{8}{15} + 2\frac{2}{15} = \frac{4}{5}$

Another easier method is, as someone suggested in the comments, remember that if X is an hypergeometric function, $E(X)=r\frac{m}{n}$

$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(k!)(n-k!)}$

$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!)(n-1-(k-1)!)}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} kp(k)$

$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} kP(X=k)$

$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{{\binom{n}{r}}}$

$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{r-k}}{{\binom{n}{r}}}$ since for $x=0$ the addend is 0.

$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\frac{\frac{m}{k}\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{n-1-(m-1)}{r-1-(k-1)}}{{\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}}}$

$E(X)=r\frac{m}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{n-1-(m-1)}{r-1-(k-1)}}{\binom{n-1}{r-1}}$ and if we say that $a=k-1$

$E(X)=r\frac{m}{n}\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{a}\binom{n-1-(m-1)}{r-1-(a)}}{\binom{n-1}{r-1}}$

The sum is 1, so $E(X)=r\frac{m}{n} = 4\frac{2}{10} = \frac{4}{5}$.

- $Var(X) = \frac{rp(1-p)(n-r)}{n-1} = \frac{4\frac{2}{40}(1-\frac{2}{40})(40-4)}{40-1} = \frac{57}{325}$ where $p=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{2}{40}$

Is this correct?

> Luca and Andrea also play together with Marco. Luca points to the
> triad of numbers {1, 5, 10}, and let Y be the random variable that
> counts the numbers guessed by Luca. Instead Andrea flips a
> well-balanced coin: if heads came up he bets on the pair {5, 10},
> while if tails came up he bets on the triad of numbers {1, 5, 10}. Let
> Z be the random variable that counts how many numbers are identified
> by Andrea.
>
> b) Write in terms of the events T = {heads} and C = {tails} and the random variables, the following events E, F, G and A, and calculate their probabilities:
>
> - E = {Marco doesn't even guess a number}
> - F = {Luca doesn't even guess a number}
> - G = {Andrea doesn't even guess a number}
> - A = {Both Marco and Andrea don't guess a single number}

My attempt:

- E = {Marco doesn't even guess a number} = $(X=0)$

  $P(E) = P(X=0) = \frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{10-2}{4-0}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{8}{4}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{1}{3}$
- F = {Luca doesn't even guess a number} = $(Y=0)$

  $P(F) = P(Y=0) = \frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{10-3}{4}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{7}{4}}{{\binom{10}{4}}} = \frac{1}{6}$
- G = {Andrea doesn't even guess a number} = $(Z=0)$

  - Let's define H={head comes out}
  - Let's define C={cross comes out}

  $P(G) = P(G|H)P(H)+P(G|C)P(C)$
  = $\frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{10-2}{4-0}}{{\binom{10}{4}}}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{10-3}{4}}{{\binom{10}{4}}}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$
- A = {Both Marco and Andrea don't guess a single number} = $(X=0)\cap(G=0)$

  $P_{X,Z}(x,z)=P_{Z}(z)P(X=x |Z=z)$

  $P_{X,Z}(0,0)=P_{Z}(0)P(X=0 |Z=0)=P(Z=0)P(X=0 |Z=0)=\frac{1}{4}1=\frac{1}{4}$

Is this correct?

> c) Knowing that Andrew didn't guess a single number, calculate the
> probability that heads and tails came up.

- G = {Andrea doesn't even guess a number} = $(Z=0)$
- Let's define H={head comes out}
- Let's define C={cross comes out}

  $P(H|G)=\frac{P(G|H)P(H)}{P(G)}=\frac{P(X=0)\frac{1}{2}}{P(Z=0)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2}{3}$

  $P(C|G)=\frac{P(G|C)P(C)}{P(G)}=\frac{P(Y=0)\frac{1}{2}}{P(Z=0)}=\frac{\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part A, you made some arithmetic mistakes in calculating the binomial coefficients for $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$. In calculating the mean, you forgot to multiply $P(X=2)$ by $2$ (but this calculation uses the incorrect values of $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$. Also note that for any Hypergeometric random variable, the mean is simply $r\tfrac{m}{n}=2(\tfrac{4}{10})=\tfrac45$. It's also safe to assume that you should redo the computation of the variance, though again for common distributions like the Hypergeometric it may be worth memorizing the mean and variance.

Comment: Perfect @Alborz, I corrected various errors that you pointed out to me and I added a proof of the expected value of a hypergeometric random variable (unfortunately I don't think I saw it in class but now it's clear and it's very handy). Do you think that is right? Do points b and c seem correct to you? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @teo nice job on the edits. Part a) looks perfect now, and part b) is nearly there. There is a mistake at the end of b) when you computed the probability of event A: $P(X=0|Z=0)=1$ since given that $Z=0$, the numbers $1,5,10$ were not selected, so definitely $5,10$ were not selected. Thus $P(A)=\tfrac14 *1=\tfrac14$. Part c) looks great. Nice work

Comment: Yes of course @Alborz, you are right, what a silly mistake. Okay, everything should be right now. I thank you again for your help and tips.